# Rails has_one per scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, has-many

I have three models as follows:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      ...
      has_many :feeds
      ...
    end

    class Project < ActiceRecord::Base
      ...
      has_many :feeds
      has_many :users, through: :feeds
      ...
    end

    class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
      ...
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :project
      ...
    end
```

I want to model the situation where a user can have a maximum of one feed per project.  I know that I can do this check in a custom validator within the Feed class, but is there a way to model this using only ActiveRecord associations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that on Feed.rb:

```
validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :project_id}
```

Comment: Thank you Anezio and sorry I accepted your answer so late.  Exactly what I was looking for.